# Why hasn't anyone been awarded the Beta badge?

Tags: support, status-completed

There is this badge that can be earned, called [Beta](https://anime.stackexchange.com/badges/30/beta).
It says that it is awarded to those who've "Actively participated in the private beta.".
I'd say some of us have done that, but none have been awarded the badge.

Is this some bug, or did we *not* actively participate in private beta?

**EDIT**
I don't mean to be a pain in the ass, but shouldn't the [badge](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/30/beta) have been awarded here on meta too?

Comment: I was thinking the same some time ago. :P

Comment: Apparently, [it has happened before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64152/no-beta-badges-generated-on-cstheory-sx).

Comment: Regarding the badge on meta - I've awarded it, just to see what would happen... But I'm not sure it's actually supposed to *exist* here!

Comment: Looks like it's just been awarded for Meta too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry for the delay - [41 users have now earned this badge!](https://anime.stackexchange.com/badges/30/beta)

Comment: Thank you Robert!